# How to apply individual classes for zii.widgets.CMenu labels?

Tags: php, css, yii, yii-components

I'm newbie to yii and I want to know:

**How to apply individual classes(CSS) for zii.widgets.CMenu labels?**

My code:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
                          'items'=>array(
                                 array('label'=>'Home', 
'url'=>array('/site/index')),<br>
                                 array('label'=>'About', 
'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),<br>
                                 array('label'=>'Contact', 
'url'=>array('/site/contact')),<br>
                                 array('label'=>'Supplier', 
'url'=>array('/supplier/index')),<br>
                                 array('label'=>'Login', 
'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                                 array('label'=>'Logout 
('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), <br>
'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
                         ),<br>
                 ));
```

Comment: you will find your answer from here.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/525/customizing-the-cmenu-widget/

Answer (score 2):

For `li` use `itemOptions` and for `a href` use `linkOptions`

**For `a href`**

```
array('label'=>'Link Lable',
      'url'=>array('controller/action'),
      'linkOptions'=>array("id"=>"link-id","class"=>"your-class1 your-class2 your-class3"), 
      'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
```

**For `li`**

```
'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'your-class1 your-class2'),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can supply itemOptions according to the official documentation that can be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu).

itemOptions, according to the documentation, are "Additional HTML attributes to be rendered for the container tag of the menu item."

This means they can be used to add HTML attributes to your items, as well as `li` elements like so:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array
(
    'items' => array
    (
        array
        (
            'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'class names here'),
            'label' => 'Home', 
            'url' => array('/site/index')),
        ),
    ),
));
```

Alternatively you can use **linkOptions** to add classes to the `a href` elements themselfs like so (note the change from *itemOptions* to *linkOptions*)

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array
(
    'items' => array
    (
        array
        (
            'linkOptions' => array('class' => 'class names here'),
            'label' => 'Home', 
            'url' => array('/site/index')),
        ),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array(
    'label'=>'Home',
    'url'=>array('/site/index'),
    'itemOptions'=>'my_class'
)
```

`itemOptions` used to customize your li attribute.